# Laravel migration: Alter column with foreign key

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to change column default value just after drop fk but still getting error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1832 Cannot change column 'training_status_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_user_training_training_status1_idx' (SQL: ALTER TABLE user_training CHANGE training_status_id training_status_id INT DEFAULT 1)
```

Migration code:

```
Schema::table('user_training', function ($table) {
           $table->dropForeign('fk_user_training_training_status1_idx');
           $table->integer('training_status_id')->default(1)->change();
           $table->foreign('training_status_id', 'fk_user_training_training_status1_idx')
               ->references('id')->on('training_status')
               ->onDelete('set null')
               ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column "training_status.id" is **unsigned**, so column "user_training.training_status_id" **must be unsigned too**, so i need to specify modifier "unsigned()".
Additionally, to drop and recreate foreign key is not necessary in migration in this case:

```
Schema::table('user_training', function ($table) {
           $table->integer('training_status_id')->default(1)->unsigned()->change();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your database has data, you can use disableForeignKeyConstraints(); to ignore the constraint:

```
Public up function(){
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

Schema::table('user_training', function ($table) {
           $table->dropForeign('fk_user_training_training_status1_idx');
           $table->integer('training_status_id')->default(1)->change();
           $table->foreign('training_status_id', 'fk_user_training_training_status1_idx')
               ->references('id')->on('training_status')
               ->onDelete('set null')
               ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Comment: Yes, database has data, but in migration i dropped foreign key just before alter column. Anyway, problem was that the referenced column has unsigned data type, so i had to specified it in migration.